# Wildfly clustered Remote EJB call in Kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, ejb, wildfly

We have project that have WildFly backend StatefulSet in three replicas, they are clustered together through JGroups.
There are remote EJBs which are accessible through Kubernetes Service (ClusterIP type)

Then there is client Deployment with one replica which calls remote EJB through InitialContext

Client side code:

```
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, actorConfig.getProvider()); //http-remoting://backend-service:80
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, actorConfig.getPrincipal());
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, actorConfig.getCredentials());
```

This approach works, remote EJB is accessible and I can run methods successfuly.

However each method runs only on pod that catch first EJB call. So there is no loadbalancing on cluster side and each task runs on one pod only.

As i read Wildfly naming client github (https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-naming-client/tree/1.0.11.Final) i see:

> all consumers of the same remote URL will share a connection. The connection lifecycle is independent of any Context instances which reference it.

From this i assume client create connection in first method call and then perserve this connection directly to one pod and stick with this.

My question is. **Am i missing som server side configuration or client side configuration?**
I want to achieve that each method call should be called on any of three backends not just one.
We are running WildFly 18 (i know, old one, but no chance to upgrade)